# Оцените стилистику такой фразы

Tags: стилистика

А ведь многие так и остаются до конца дней в своем маленьком мирке
«яичной скорлупы». (Пару лет назад при публикации в газете два последних слова были вырезаны редактором.)

Comment: Здесь бы дать комментарий, название или пошире цитату из публикации!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, править стилистику автора — дело последнее, за исключением тех случаев, когда она содержит явную ошибку. Тут я соглашусь с теми, кто высказывался до меня.
И всё же в 
этом примере есть на как раз такая ошибка: «мирок яичной скорлупы». Дело в том, что подразумевается выражение «он живёт в скорлупе» или «не выглядывает из своей скорлупы», т.е. содержится внутри, в ней, в скорлупе. В!

А что говорит данная фраза? Она не говорит о мирке «под яичной скорлупой» или мирке «в яичной скорлупе», или хотя бы о мирке «внутри яичной скорлупы», ну или на крайний случай мирке «за яичной скорлупой» — что, конечно, дикость с точки зрения смысла и стиля, но хотя бы имеет верное направление.

Т.е. данная фраза, не содержит всех этих смыслов, а говорит буквально один из двух следующих вариантов:

1) Мир яичной скорлупы — т.е. мир, где эта скорлупа обитает, её, подобно тому, как мы можем назвать Антарктиду миром какого-нибудь пингвина или моржа;

2) Мир яичной скорлупы — т.е. мир самой скорлупы, находящийся в самом составе скорлупы, содержащийся в ней, подобно тому, как мир дикой природы — это то, что находится в самой этой дикой природе и ограничивается ею, а не простирается где-то вне её.

Так что, не смотря на то, что интуитивно авторская мысль понятна, сформулирована она не правильно. Мы с тем же успехом могли бы назвать Китай миром Великой Китайской стены, что характеризовало бы эту страну, как находящуюся исключительно в данном архитектурном сооружении, а не за ним.

Comment: Был не так давно в солончаке Уюни (Боливия), где все постройки и мебель сделаны из соли, а посему предлагаю третий вариант. "Мир скорлупы" - это такой мир, где посуда, одежда, и все остальное изготовлено из этого странного материала. А если серьезно, книга уже опубликована. И эту строку я удалил, как непонятную для общественности. http://krymizdat.ru/03449

Answer (score 0):

Правильно были вырезаны. "Мирок скорлупы" трудно представить.

Comment: Вот и мне тоже трудно его представить, тем не менее, многие в нем живут. Не убедительно, нужен конкретный довод, ув. Никто.

Comment: А строгих математических доказательств в стилистике не бывает, ув. Победитель. Спросите еще у других, если сами не чувствуете.

Естественно, если и "яичной" убрать, все равно не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь редактор, видимо, вырезал вначале не понравившееся ему своей натуралистичностью и несомасштабностью человеку слово *яичной*. Можно было бы оставить: в маленьком мирке своей скорлупы, но он решил, что и так нормально будет.

Comment: Вы,- я посмотрел,- из Москвы, а есть люди, которые живут в маленьких провинциальных городках (насчет деревень, вообще молчу) и они даже не предполагают, что там за холмом... Загранпаспортов никогда не имели. Это ведь аллегория, насчет скорлупы. Конечно, если жить в Москве и никуде не ездить, это уже не "скорлупа".

Comment: Оказывается, это не аллегория вовсе была, а провинциальные страсти! Я ошибся, но намеренно, из-за отсутствия контекста, как тут часто случается. Пишите развёрнутый вопрос, может быть, поясняйте его в комментарии к вопросу. Нельзя считать контекстом то, что «Пару лет назад редактор...».

Comment: Причем тут страсти-мордасти? Вот контекст, пожалуйста...        Когда-то в детстве мир казался мне огромным: двухэтажные постройки – великанами, а поездка на ялтинскую Поляну сказок, или в Бахчисарайский дворец… О-о! Прошло время, многое изменилось.Небоскребы Токио и Гонконга, острова Океании… И это не предел. А ведь многие так и остаются до конца дней в своем маленьком мирке «яичной скорлупы».   В принципе, к жителям Москвы, не имевшим никогда загранпаспорта, это тоже относится. Только скорлупа в этом случае - страусиная. :-)

Comment: Проблема, действительно, в "яичной" - иначе "скорлупу" можно было бы сопоставить напр. с чеховским "футляром". Такую аллегорию трудно понять, если она взята не из жизни птиц. Но если таки эксплуатировать аналогию птичьей жизни с человеческой, то становится не по себе: "конец дней" застаёт в "мирке яичной скорлупы" в двух типичных случаях: хищник полакомился её содержимым или яичницу кто-то сделал. :)

Comment: А у Чехова что, человек в мирке футляра? Или все-таки в футляре? Чехов был неплохой стилист, мирок футляра (как и мирок яичной скорлупы) он бы не допустил.
Коль уж мы о скорлупе, то могу сказать, что "проблема" не стоит выеденного яйца.

Comment: @Alex_ander Да, в целом аналогия верна. А я как-то и забыл, что подобное уже было в литературе. Только, в моем случае оно как бы обиднее звучит. ...Для человека истинно домашнего, домоседа. Но яичница и хищник здесь не при чем. Речь о человеке, который вырос из этой "скорлупы", как из своих детских брюк, но по прежнему живет в ней, возвращаясь в нее вечерами после работы. Но если написанное понятно только автору, это плохо...

Answer (score 0):

Вот возможный вариант замены авторской фразы. Хотя это немного не то...

*А ведь многие так и остаются до конца дней в своем маленьком мирке "дом-работа-дом", словно великовозрастные младенцы, выросшие из полюбившихся чепцов и ползунков.*

Comment: Да, с грамматикой все верно, но сравнивать этих "многих", на которых (не люблю красивых слов, но все же) держится мир, с младенцами? Не знаю, не знаю. Они работают до конца дней, а автор сибаритствует и эдак снисходительно *нравоучает*?

Comment: В Вопросе: Оцените стилистику такой фразы. Это не ответ.

Comment: Поскольку я заменил неугодные обществу (по большинству голосов) слова, значит я ОЦЕНИЛ их как неудовлетворительные. Чем не ответ?

Comment: Виктор, вы басню со словами "суди, дружок, не выше сапога" читали? Это я насчет неугодных обществу слов.

Comment: А shampar прав по крайней мере в одном. Формально это гвоздь не от той стены. В смысле: ваш вопрос не от вашего ответа. Или наоборот, как уж вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

> А ведь многие так и остаются до конца дней в своем маленьком мирке
>   «яичной скорлупы».

Не вижу необходимости что-то менять, если это авторский стиль. Вообще стилистику, если это не очевидный ляп школьного уровня, надо оценивать совокупно по всему произведению.

Вам пора уже нанимать литературного редактора и корректора. А то подобная работа в таком масштабе - это уже дело профессионалов, не можем же мы вам всю книгу выправить. Тем более, мы сами не сможет договориться, когда тут пять человек всегда имеют шесть противоположных мнений.

Comment: Сегодня я ввел последний вопрос… по текущей брошюре, но она не последняя…:-) В таких вопросах, как эта «злополучная» скорлупа, мнение редактокорректора может быть субъективным. Тут нужно голосование. (А повышенное кол-во тем от одного участника здесь не приветствуется?)

Answer (score 0):

Хороший эпитет, грустный, честный. В следующих предложениях текста тоже убрали? Про страусиную? 
Я вижу так - и хорошо вижу: кажущаяся надёжность, небольшое обтекаемое привычное пространство, но это изнутри. Для наблюдателя: нечто хрупкое,  преходящее, такое малое, что можно не заметить.
Далее вы иронизируете про стаусиную скорлупу. Такие же ассоциации, чистая ирония: кажущееся величие, хоть и такое же хрупкое и поддающееся разрушению. Натуралистично - да. Приземлённо даже. Несоразмерно? Поспорю: всяк человек сам изначально был крохотной клеточкой, которая торопливо росла и делилась.

Comment: Если, конечно, мой рейтинг вас не насмешит. :-)

Comment: Вы слишком много рейтингу внимания уделяете. ))

Comment: Мимо! Я просто очень люблю шутить, особенно над собой, хотя, возможно, и не умею! Но это всё вода, к делу отношения не имеет.

Comment: Значит шуткам своим слишком много внимания уделяете. Короче, прошу больше не засорять ресурс тем, что "к делу. не имеет отношения".